# Is it Possible to search within dc.js graphs (ex: row chart)?

Tags: search, d3.js, dc.js

Suppose we have row chart with some rows.

On entering text and clicking a button can we focus to a particular row in a rowchart?

If yes, please suggest some example.

Comment: I'm unclear what you're asking. Do you mean filter on the row that was clicked? That's the default behavior, just take a look at the main page and the annotated source.

Comment: @Gordon   .Thanks for reply.   I have textbox besides to row graph .if i enter any text(any row (data/label))   and click on button it should focus on that row. is that possible

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the [`chart.filter` method](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#filterfiltervalue).

In your handler for the button click event, just call

```
rowChart.filter(value);
```

with the `value` from the text box.

Comment: Hi thanks for Reply. may be i didn't explain my question correctly.i dont want to filter the chart.i just want to search is entered text available in graph or not ?,if avaialable just go to that row (dont filter grpah).       (ex: as like we do search in (Notepad/Word ) using CTRL+F)

Comment: explained example may be stupid .but i want to do like that in my scenario.

Comment: So you want to highlight all bars that match the text search in another color?

Comment: yes.(ex :: if we have 100 rows in row chart.and if i searched for last row  can we heighlight that